# Removing element from ng-repeat does not allow to remove or hide element from DOM

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have below code to display records using ng-repeat:

```
<div class="gallery">
        <div ng-cloak
             ng-repeat="photo in photos| orderBy:'-id'"
             ng-mouseLeave = "delete_btn = !delete_btn"
             ng-mouseEnter = "delete_btn = !delete_btn"
             class="gallery_block"
             id="photo_block_[[photo.id]]">
            <span title="delete photo" ng-show="delete_btn" class="delete_btn_span" rel="[[photo.id]]" id="delete_photo_[[photo.id]]">
               <img  src="{{asset('frontend/images/cross_icon.png')}}">
            </span>
            <p>
                <a href="javascript:;">
                    <img ng-click="showImagePopup([[photo.path_popup_thumbnail]]);" src={{$public_path}}./image.php?width=149&height=109&cropratio=2:1.4&image=[[photo.path_popup_thumbnail]] alt="">
                </a>
                {{--<span> </span>--}}
            </p>
        </div>

    </div>
```

I have to delete records for that I first have to call a function using $http and then I remove element from photos array:

```
  var index = $scope.photos.indexOf($('#photo_block_'+id));
        $scope.photos.splice(index, 1);
```

Then I remove element from DOM:

```
$('#photo_block_'+id).remove();
```

**Update**
I have called deletePhoto function using jqyery like below:

```
 $(".gallery").on('click','span.delete_btn_span',function()
{   
    $scope.deletePhoto($(elem), $(elem).attr('rel'));
});
```

deletePhoto function further do all the work of deleting elements etc.
But it does not remove element. Where as all the selectors are fine.
Is removing element from photos array causing problem?

Comment: Stop using jquery. The $scope.photos array doesn't contain jquery objects. It just contains photo objects. So $scope.photos.indexOf($('#photo_block_'+id)) will always be -1. Your delete button should have `ng-click="deletePhoto(photo)". And deletePhoto() should simply remove the passed photo from the array. angular will redisplay the array automatically.

Comment: Your selector(`$('#photo_block_'+id)`) is look like jquery are you using jquery?

Comment: But it is not redisplaying and element remains there. BTW I used .hide() instead of remove and removing the element from array and it is behaving fine.

Comment: Yes I am using jQuery also.

Comment: Utilization of ng-if will better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With angular JS, you have to deal with data. So you should put an `ng-click="delete(photo)"` on your span.

and create a method in your controller :

`$scope.delete = function(photo) {
// delete froms scope.photos here...
}`

to delete the photo from the list.

Your code does not work because `$scope.photos.indexOf($('#photo_block_'+id))` surely return -1, because you're looking for $('#photo_block_'+id), which is a jquery object in a list of simple json object (i suppose).

So the splice method does anything, and the $scope.photos list remain unchanged, so the view is not changed, because it's build from the list by the ng-repeat directive.

ps: you should never manipulate dom element from controller, if you need to do that, you should create directive.

Comment: I have to call deletePhoto using jquery as my delete button does not exist in DOM initially so ng-click gives inprog error of angular. there I used $timeout of angular and wrapped call to deletePhotos within it.

Comment: What should I pass in $scope.photos.indexOf(?) ??

Comment: why do you say that your delete button does not exist initally ? One different button will be create for each iteration by the ng-repeat directive... your button is only hidden by ng-show... if you use ng-click="deletePhoto(photo)" on the span, your deletePhoto method will be call with the photo to delete in parameter, then you can delete it from the list...

Comment: Because user can add new records.

Comment: it does not matter, i expect that when user add record, you juste add a new element to the $scope.photos ? (i hope...) Everytime $scope.photos is updated, angular will update the view, so it will also create a delete button for the new created record.

Comment: Yes you are right @BAXOM it does not give me error to apply ng-click directly to delete button. I don't know why it initially gave me error of $improg. Now I have passed photo to deletePhoto(photo.id, photo)  and sliced array item. Working fine.